# How to get new windows and notifications to appear in current workspace.

Tags: gnome

I have not yet found a question like this, and that surprises me.

I have Ubuntu 11.04 with Compiz and Gnome 2.x

What I would love to have is for applications to open on the workspace that I'm in on the moment I click on their icon.

Usually what happens is that you click on an application, you will get a "Starting application" in your task bar, and then the application will open in whatever workspace you're in.

So a typical example is that I'm in my programming in my IDE, and I hit the debug button, and switch to another workspace to check my mails while my application is compiling. When it is done, I want it to spawn a window in the original workspace, and not in front of my mail client, so that I have to move it back up (seems like a waste of time + it's annoying)

Same thing for applications that spawn new windows: It should open in the same workspace as the application that spawns it.

This isn't about opening specific applications in specific workspaces, because I don't want to configure this for each of my applications. I want a global solution.

Any help? This has been bugging me about ubuntu in general for years now.

Comment: You could try to use devilspie. I do not know a more generic way. I file this as a comment as I cannot give a stepwise explanation to solve your problem using devilspie. If you managed it, please post an answer yourself, I am also interested in it

Comment: I've heard about that before. I'll look into it. Thx

Comment: I've looked at it and devilspie doesn't have an option (unless I completely missed it) to do what I stated above. I could still manually set each application individually, but this seems like more of a workaround than an actual solution. Again, still looking for a general solution (that is dynamic), and not a case-by-case solution that is configured statically.

Answer (score 2):

You can workaround this  issue with [Compiz Settings Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager):

**1)** [Install ccsm](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager),

**2)** Open it (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `ccsm` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>),

**3)** Go to "Windows Management" > "Place Windows",

[image]

**4)** Open the tab "Fixed Windows Placement",

[image]

**5)** Under "Windows with fixed viewport" click at "New". At the new opened windows click at the <kbd>+</kbd> to add the program you want to configure.

[image]

[image]

Enjoy ;-)

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you put into your answer, but I was looking for a more general approach to my problem instead of a statically defined manual per-application solution. this is almost equivalent to the devilspie solution suggested by a user above. Though, to show I'm not a bad person, I'll give you the bounty if nobody comes up with a more general solution in the next 3 days.

Comment: Also, a quote from my original question: "This isn't about opening specific applications in specific workspaces, because I don't want to configure this for each of my applications. I want a global solution."

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that. I will do some research.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't find your answer yet.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the effort. I'm giving you the bounty. I don't think this is possible in ubuntu, I guess it is just one of its flaws. I'm now using your workaround, which is better, but still has some annoyances such as, when I move (lets say firefox) to another workspace, it will still spawn its own new windows in the original hard-coded workspace, which can get confusing at times. Anyway, thanks for trying!

Comment: Thank you. I think this is annoying too therefore I will continue the research and I will put a solution here if I find.